# calculating SNR for a Signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am adding some white Gaussian noise on a signal in MATLAB 2008 R2

```
noisedSignal = awgn(signal, 25);% 25 is the SNR
```

but then when I calculate the SNR in the `noisedSignal`

```
snr = GetSNR(noisedSignal, noisedSignal-signal);
```

and

```
function SNR = GetSNR(signal, errorSignal)
    SNR = 20 * log10(sqrt(mean(signal.^2))/sqrt(mean(errorSignal.^2)));
end
```

the `SNR` calculated is 1.1818 which is not 25. What am I missing ?

Comment: i cannot reproduce your result. I can get ~25 with your code.

Comment: what is your input signal @lennon310

Answer (score 4):

You should take this into account:

- `awgn` assumes the signal has unit power
- the `SNR` argument of `awgn` is in dB
- SNR is estimated as power of signal divided by power of noise, or approximately power of noised signal divided by power of noise.

See the following example:

```
signal = randn(1,1e6); %// example signal with approximately unit power
S = mean(signal.^2); %// actual signal power
noisedSignal = awgn(signal, 25);
SN = mean(noisedSignal.^2); %// power of noised signal
N = mean((signal-noisedSignal).^2);
SN/N
10^(25/10)
```

This gives

```
ans =
  316.9019
ans =
  316.2278
```

so the computed SNR (`SN/N`) is very similar to the expected value (`10^(25/10)`).

Comment: what does it means a unit power ? and what if my signal isnot a signal power ? cz in my case the signal I am using is a Human speech signal... 

Also in calculating the SN/N , shouldnt you use RMS(SN)/RMS(N) ?? why u just used the mean square of the SN and N ?

Comment: @Kasparov92 I use mean square because that's what power means: mean of squared values. (In your case you have `sqrt` but then multiply by 20 to get the dB, so it's the same). If your signal doesn't have unit power, you should interpret the `SNR` argument of `awgn` not as SNR, but as noise power

Comment: ohh i seee 
Thanks a lot @Luis
I wishe I could upvote ur answer but I need more reputation points :$

Comment: @Kasparov92 Welcom! Glad I could help :-)

Comment: I tried mean(signal.^2) with different ranges and they were all ~ 1 .. is it cz randn is based on a normal distribution or something ?

Comment: anyway now things are much clearer .. but still my question about what shall I do about the input when it is not unit of power ... I am having the SNR ( calculated Ps/Pn ) gives me 1.1550 which when transformed to decibel is = 10 log(1.550) = 0.6259 still not even close to 25 !! @Luis Mendo